# Iterate over an array and get all multiples of 10 java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am very new to Java and I am trying to iterate over an array of integers and get all multiples of 10. What I get with my code is the elements in the array printed 100 times since that is the length of the array. I know it is very basic but I just can't figure the problem out. This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayThings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myFirstArray = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < myFirstArray.length; i++) {
            myFirstArray[i] = i;
        }

        for (int i : myFirstArray) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                myFirstArray[i] = i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myFirstArray));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want an array of 100 elements, which are the 100 first multiples of 10 ?

Comment: No, i want the multiples of 10 between 1 and 99.

Comment: To get the mutliples of 10 you don't need an array at all...

Comment: inside this loop `for (int i : myFirstArray)` you increase i - `i++`. don't so this

Comment: What do you think `myFirstArray[i] = i;` and `i++;` do in the second loop? (Hint: the answer is nothing.)

Comment: Replace 100 by 1,000,000. What mechanism would you use to find and display the multiples of 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is what you want to do :

```
public class ArrayThings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myFirstArray = new int[100];

        // array generation
        for (int i = 0; i < myFirstArray.length; i++) {
            myFirstArray[i] = i;
        }
        // printing multiples of 10
        for (int i = 0; i < myFirstArray.length; i++) {
            if (i % 10 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.println(myFirstArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java-8 you can do it like below:

```
int result[] = IntStream.range(1, 100).filter(e -> e%10==0).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an array for printing multiples of 10? You could simply do:

```
 public class ArrayThings{
          public static void main(String[]args){
            for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
                if(i%10==0 && i != 0){
                System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

        }}
```

P.S. you are printing whole array and not that particular element, that's why you are getting a wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayThings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myFirstArray = new int[100];
        int[] myMultiplesArray = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < myFirstArray.length; i++) {
            myFirstArray[i] = i;
        }

        int j = 0;

        for (int i : myFirstArray) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                myMultiplesArray[j] = i;
                j++;
            } 

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMultiplesArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's incorrect variant! `i` variable is assigned by for-each loop construct

Answer (score 0):

You should move your print statement outside of the for loop, that is what is causing it to print 100 times.

Also your current code seems to do absolutely nothing.  You are checking the modulo of i, then setting the value of myFirstArray to that value of i.  The current value of myFirstArray at i, is already equal to i, as initialized in the first loop.